# Meaning of ~. operator in R

Tags: r

Can someone explain me the below line of code. I am very new to R. 
I am finding it difficult to understand the below line of code

```
xtabs(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ ., data = esoph)
```

Here `xtabs` function is used to build a table using `ncases` and `ncontrols`.
Is my understanding is right
why `~.` function is used after `cbind` function
Can someone explain in detail

Comment: The `?xtabs` doc probably covers it.

Comment: In general, `~` is a way to denote statistical models. Things at the left are the responses, things at the right are explanatory varibles.

Comment: You can get the details on this type of expression by typing `?formula`

Comment: You say "why ~. function is used after cbind function"  It would be helpful if you would give a sample of code so that we would know just what you are looking at.

Comment: `~.` means basically: "by (or as a function of) all other variables in the data frame not mentioned on the left hand side".